# use tastypie for non-crud operations

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I'm starting with tasty pie and have a few questions, I'm a little lost.
As I could see, I can create a resource using ModelResource if I'm using a django model or use only Resource if I'm using a non-orm resource. But what I don't understand is if I always have to "map" a tastypie resource with some entity. What if I don't need to use CRUD operations? for example temperature conversions or math operations where I don't need to query any table? or for instance if I only want an api called /status where I query a few tables, make some calculations and return only an "up" string in json format or something like that when I do a GET request? Is tasty useful for this?
thanks!

Comment: I've been reading about django rest framework, and has more documentation about this kind of situations, so since I'm just starting, I think I will change to that framework, unless someone tell me that it's easy to implement in tasty as well